# How to output identification of template arg T at design-time compilation?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++23

always had this question and never asked, and running into a internal compilation error with hundreds of types.  I just want to output the name of T, while its actually designing the functions, design-time compilation.

seems utterly the easiest thing to implement in a compiler?  pragma message, pragma type.  these things call when its generating them, so i see the message print over and over.

with msvc, an xmacro to get the name didnt work.  i didnt want to add that to this question but it should be known i tried that too..

```
template <typename T>
void abc(T v) {

     /// not allowed (and i see no other pragmas?)
     #pragma message(T) // i need to output something identifying int.  doesnt have to be int but anything special even a hash or a size at the compilation stage here

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   abc(int(1));
   return 0;
}
```

pragma is definitely outputting multiple times, its not like its some run-once thing.  i see lots and lots of logs so its evaling with potential type name resolution.  nothing at all available?

Comment: I often create a struct like `template <typename T> struct get_type;` and then I use it in my code like `get_type<some_type_I_want_to_know>{};` and that gives you a compiler error like `cant create class of incomplete type with T = some_type_I_want_to_know`

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. What is a "design time compiler"? What are `str` and `T`? What is the purpose of this code?

Comment: its just inside of a static on ident::for_type<T>, which fills out generic lambdas

Comment: @KalenWhite: "*its just inside of a static on ident::for_type<T>*" What is "it" that is "just inside of a static"? How is anything "inside of a static"? Do you mean that the code is inside of a static member function? If so, explain that in the question, along with the rest of the stuff that is unexplained (like the meaning of those identifiers and what the goal of the code is).

Comment: ill just reduce the question.  how to output a template arg.  the rest is just in the way of that direct question

Comment: `#pragma` cannot possibly work because it is for _pre-processor_: like `#define` it is expanded before actual compilation. You can try to generate warnings containing type name, e.g.: `if (false) { printf("%d", (T*)(nullptr)); }` prints something like: `format string '%d' requires an argument of type 'int', but variadic argument 1 has type 'std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>> *'`

Comment: @KalenWhite: Are you going to edit the question to reflect this? And what do you mean by "output a template arg"? Output it to what?

Comment: @KalenWhite: What is "design-time compilation"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#pragma message(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__)
```

this prints what i need.. i tried `__FUNCTION__` and that was just class::method, but this beauty gives:

```
struct ident *__cdecl ident::for_type<struct array<enum VkFormat>::adata,false>(void)
```

things like that.. and thats very valuable.. much more valuable than bifurcating through a million types.

Comment: ... you asked about a template parameter, not a function signature. How could anybody guess that this would be a valid answer to the question as asked?

Comment: 'identification of template arg T' resolved.  also, proof-case that this is not a pre-processor domain-only.  the parameter is in the arg, and in the return type.   getting the function signature contains identity.  i ran this and it generated about 5000 messages in less than a few seconds, this is not pre-processor level because c++ is not preprocessed for every templated generation.  its called design-time.

Comment: This actually a nice find, because it can be defined as a separate function, e.g. `template <typename T> T* pragma_message_type() { #pragma message(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__) return nullptr; }` and invoked when needed with arbitrary type, e.g. `pragma_message_type<std::vector<int>::size_type>();`

Comment: Also, `__FUNCSIG__` can be used with MSVC since it does not support `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`

Comment: Hmm, it does not seems to work at all with gcc and `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`: https://godbolt.org/z/MxeneMTEa, only with MSVC and `__FUNCSIG__`

Comment: @dewaffled supports the ``__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`` on the build i am using, c++ experimental modules in msvc vs2022..

Comment: @waffled on gcc does it just print once regardless? ... say you create 10 types is it just going to give you the pragma message on 1st pre-compile?